# Pandas: How to increase the date of every entry in the date column by a certain days without using for loop

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has data like:

```
Date            Day     Sometext
2017-02-02       10     abcd
2017-02-02       11     efgh
2017-02-02       12     ijhk
2017-02-02       13     asbg
2017-02-02       14     asg
:                 :
:                 :
:                 :
2017-02-02       30     aslk
```

I need to get the dataframe such that it looks like below:

```
Date            Day     Sometext
2017-02-12       10     abcd
2017-02-13       11     efgh
2017-02-14       12     ijhk
2017-02-15       13     asbg
2017-02-16       14     asg
:                 :
:                 :
:                 :
2017-03-04       30     aslkj
```

I have startDate which is equal to "2017-02-02". 
Right now what I am doing is:

```
epi_df['Date'] = startDate
for i,rowData in epi_df.iterrows():
    epi_df['Date'].iloc[i] = startDate + pd.to_timedelta(rowData['Day'], unit='d')
```

This achieves my result but is very slow. Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Day'], unit='d')
```

You get

```
    Date        Day Sometext
0   2017-02-12  10  abcd
1   2017-02-13  11  efgh
2   2017-02-14  12  ijhk
3   2017-02-15  13  asbg
4   2017-02-16  14  asg
```